# '%' symbols in a URL string interpreted as comment characters

Tags: bibtex, urls

I want to add an online link in the bibliography section.

```
@online{xx,
author = {xy},
  title={yz},
url={https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20(in%20particular%2C%20functional,the%20process%20of%20computing%20it.},
  urldate = {zx}
}
```

As we can see the URL section contains '%' in it and latex interpreting it as a comment. How can I solve it?

Comment: Remember to load the url or xurl package. Additionally please post a full but minimal example so we can see what you're actually doing in your document

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What's important, for the information contained in the URL string is not `%` but `%20`, which represents interword whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You -- or somebody else -- would appear to have created the URL you show in your query from the very first full sentence of the Wikipedia entry at `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution`. (The multitude of `%20` triples all respresent interword space.)

For the sake of providing useful, and usable, information for your readers, I simply cannot see a reason for having anything but `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution` in the bib entry, making it

```
@online{xx,
  author = {xy},
  title={yz},
  url={https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution},
  urldate = {zx}
}
```

Comment: It goes without saying, maybe, that you should also load the `xurl` package, to simplify the creation of line breaks, as needed, in long URL strings.