# How to cite a youtube video (with URL when there are percentage signs)?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, urls, percent-sign

I would like to cite this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo46TEp6FB8&ab_channel=InstitutdesHautes%C3%89tudesScientifiques%28IH%C3%89S%29 in an overleaf file.

I'm not sure how this is done ( usually I would just go on google scholar and copy and paste the the  bibtex citation they provide into my bibliography file). How do I proceed here (especially as the URL has percentage signs in it)?

Comment: the general question about url with percent signs depends on your bibliography system, but for youtube concretly, simply use the short version of the url you get by right clicking on the video.  You don't all the additional stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that when you cite the URL, the % signs are interpreted as comment command. I faced the same issue asked [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590325/symbols-in-a-url-string-interpreted-as-comment-characters). You don't need to cite the whole URL. Only citing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo46TEp6FB8 will do the work. Head to the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590325/symbols-in-a-url-string-interpreted-as-comment-characters) for details.

Comment: @Monty  If the answer helped you, it'd be cool if you could "accept" it by clicking on the checkmark symbol. It will also help to close the question. Cheers!